# Defining an error list for the convergence to pi

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm trying to model the convergence of a series towards pi based on a defined term. I've managed to create a list that returns the approximate value for pi at each iteration, however, I'm struggling to create a list that returns the difference between the approximation for pi and math.pi. I understand that the code is currently just looping the error term for one value of pi, and I don't know how to loop it over n values of pi. I'm sure it's a simple fix that I'm just overlooking so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here's my code:

```
from math import pi
from math import factorial

def term_in_series_1(n):
    values=[] 
    for k in range (n, -1,-1): #Here we are creating a for loop starting at n, finishing at -1 with a stepsize of -1
        value_of_term_n = 2 * 2**k * (factorial(k))**2 / factorial(2*k+1) #The loop uses this equation to calculate the value term of n for values in the range of n 
        values.append(value_of_term_n) #The append function allows each new value term of n to be added to the empty list "values" with length n
    return values

def series_1(n):
    approximation_for_pi = sum(term_in_series_1(n)) #This line is taking the sum of all the values in the series calulated in the previous function
    return approximation_for_pi

def error_1(j):
    values=[] 
    for i in range (j):
        for k in range (n):
            value_of_error_1 = pi - series_1(n) #The loop uses this equation to calculate the value term of n for values in the range of n 
            values.append(value_of_error_1) #The append function allows each new value term of n to be added to the empty list "values" with length n
        return values
error_1(15)
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to be the problem:

```
for i in range (j):
    value_of_error_1 = pi - series_1(n)
```

You have an iteration variable `i` but refer to `n` out of nowhere.  Assuming the iteration variable should be `n`, here's a rework of your code:

```
from math import pi, factorial

def term_in_series_1(n):
    values = []

    for k in range(n, -1, -1):
        value_of_term_n = 2 * 2**k * factorial(k)**2 / factorial(2*k+1)
        values.append(value_of_term_n)

    return values

def series_1(n):
    return sum(term_in_series_1(n))

def error_1(j):
    errors = []

    for n in range(j):
        errors.append(pi - series_1(n))

    return errors

print(error_1(10))
```

Comment: Shouldn't this just be closed as a typo?

Comment: Barmar, I agree.